# Removing initial whitespace plus the last empty new line line using python

Tags: python, string, whitespace, indentation

I am trying to implement a code that prints an 8 by 8 matrix (0 to 63). It should however remove the initial tab spaces and the last empty line. My code is below :

```
s =''
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        z = i * n + j
        s += ' '
        if z < 10:
            s += ' '
        s += str(z)
    s += '\n'
print(s)
```

The image Below is also the desired output

[image]

I have tried the dedent function but it fails to remove the last line as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically all you are looking for is whenever you go to a new line, the initial space is not printed, since every newline is a j, you will need to add:

```py
        if j != 0:
            s += ' '
```

It should work. Will look like this now:

```py
s =''
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        z = i * n + j

        if j != 0:
            s += ' '
        
        if z < 10:
            s += ' '
        s += str(z)
    
    if i != j:
        s += '\n'
print(s)
```

Let me know if it has any problems.

Comment: It prints a last empty line

Comment: Code Snippet has been modified. added an `i != j` at the end since he last line is when both i and j are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try

```py
n = 8 
print("\n".join([" ".join(["{:2d}".format(i*n+j) for j in range(n)]) for i in range(n) ]), end="")
```

Output:

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55
56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63
```

Comment: Prints a different output . The numbers 1 - 7 for example are on a column rather than a row

Comment: Just replace the order of `i` and `j` in the for loop clause. i.e. `print("\n".join([" ".join(["{:2d}".format(i*n+j) for j in range(n)]) for i in range(n) ]), end="")`